# syntax confusion with creating a new struct type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, callback, typedef

```
    struct I2C_CALLBACK_STRUCT
    {
        HANDLE  (*I2C_OpenDevice)(UINT32 port, UINT32 freq);
        BOOLEAN  (*I2C_CloseDevice)(HANDLE handle);
    };

    typedef struct I2C_CALLBACK_STRUCT  I2C_CALLBACKS_T,    *I2C_CALLBACKS_PTR;

    static const I2C_CALLBACKS_T I2C_Callback =
    {
        OpenI2CPort,
        CloseI2CPort,
    };
```

Could someone step through the above code and explain what is happening? I understand filling a struct with function pointers, but I don't understand what happens when you use the typedef to create the new types `I2C_CALLBACKS_T` and `*I2C_CALLBACKS_PTR`. Also I don't understand the syntax used when creating `I2C_Callback` ie. why is an equals sign used, as that is not something I am familiar with

I apologise for rambling on, I'm not sure of the best way to word my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) `typedef`**

What you are doing with `typedef` is creating two new types, `I2C_CALLBACKS_T` and `I2C_CALLBACKS_PTR`. You do this so you don't have to write `struct` keyword before defining your structure:

```
I2C_CALLBACKS_T a; // shorter
struct I2C_CALLBACK_STRUCT a; //longer
```

The type `I2C_CALLBACKS_PTR` is useful because you don't have to explicitly define pointers to structure:

```
I2C_CALLBACKS_PTR a, b, c; // shorter
I2C_CALLBACKS_T *a, *b, *c; // longer
```

**2) Structure initialization**

Then, `I2C_Callback` struct's function pointers just gets mapped to `OpenI2CPort` and `CloseI2CPort` functions.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it would be clearer, if you remove all the "garbage" characters like:

```
// structure decalaration
struct callback
{
  FUNCPTR1 function1;
  FUNCPTR2 function2;
};

// getting rid of always typing `struct` and using a more convenient name
typedef struct callback CALLBACK;
typedef struct callback *CALLBACKPTR; // this one is bad behaviour if used, disturbing the reader of your code

// defining a callback-variable with initialization
CALLBACK c = {fun1, fun2};
// the same:
struct callback c = {fun1, fun2};
// which is, more-or-less, equivalent to: (if it is used inside a scope of afunction):
struct callback c;
c.function1 = fun1;
c.function2 = fun2;
```

the `equal`-sign is to be read as an `assignment`-sign.